# Dynamic adding apps to Django

Tags: django

I'm building a backend with some core-functionality app (which means, of course, a single DB for the app).
I'm looking for elegant way to create app for every new customer by "copying" some template (basic) app to be able modify every's customer app with specific customer's requirements.

For ex., I have some basic StoreApp in Django. It could have some basic features, models etc. Now, when some new customer wants to sign up, I want dynamically (not manually) create additional copy of the existing StoreApp (of course, under different name and its own DB), make initial migration for it, register it in the settings and so on. Lately, I want to customize this new app according to the customer's requirements. I'm just looking for a way to separate code maintenance for every existing app, but, as I mentioned before, not to create every app manually.
Any elegant way to do it? Some existing plugin for Django?

Thanks in advance,
Efi

Comment: I would not recommend doing this. Suppose you have 1000 customers, then you have 1000 apps.  Please elaborate on what you want to do, so that we can try to find better methods to achieve it rather that create a new app everytime. That being said, you can easily create new apps by calling subprocesses and threads. Look at python subprocess and thread module

Comment: Thanks, will try to do this.
BTW, why could it be a problem - having a unique app for every customer, if I'm planning to customize some base app according to the customer's requirements? Sounds simpler than try to figure out a "common divider" for all the customers and manage business logic in the same code for all the customers.